# Unable to load Visual Studio 2015 project after adding dependency on Microsoft.Net.Compilers

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, c#-6.0

My project has a dependency on the NuGet package `Microsoft.Net.Compilers`:

```
<package id="Microsoft.Net.Compilers" version="1.3.2" 
         targetFramework="net461" developmentDependency="true" />
```

However, if I'm loading Visual Studio after having cleared my packages folder my projects won't load with the following error:

> The imported project "C:\MyService\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.1.3.2\tools\Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in the  declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.CSharp.CurrentVersion.targets

So it won't load the project because it's missing a file which is restored on build using Nuget, which only works if I can load the project.

Comment: Use the NuGet commandline executable to call `nuget restore`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the Nuget commandline tool to restore your packages. If your system doesn't yet have it, you can find it here: https://www.nuget.org/

Issue this on the commandline:

```
nuget restore
```